# Make rows out of one column based on another columns value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this

```
V1 V2
10 5
20 4
30 8
40 6
10 10
20 7
30 4
40 9
```

And I would like to have all the values relating to the same V1 in one row, like so...

```
V1 V2 V3
10 5 10
20 4 7
30 8 4
40 6 9
```

Comment: Will there always be exactly two V2s for each unique V1?

Comment: Yes, actually 100 V2s for each unique V1

Comment: Is order in any way important?

Comment: No doesn't matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution in base R. You can feed the uniques in row V1 into a lapply and extract all values in V2 for each unique V1. This you feed into a call to do.call (because the result from lapply is a list) with rbind, and then you merge the resulting matrix with the vector of uniques via cbind.

```
# Create df1 for demonstration
df1 = data.frame(a = rep(1:4, 10), b = sample(1:40))
output = cbind(unique(df1$a), do.call(rbind, lapply(unique(df1$a), function(x) df1$b[df1$a == x])))
```

This solution depends on the values inside the source data frame to be of the same type. If they are not, you might have to invest some time into casting the data into the correct types or so. But this should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you want with apply functions.

```
DF <- data.frame(A = c(1:5,1:5),B=11:20)

lst <- lapply(unique(DF$A),function(AA) DF[DF$A ==AA,'B'])

Result <- do.call(rbind,lst)
```

If you wish to have the A column back in you can use `Results <- cbind(A=names(lst),Results)`

Be careful, this will give you a matrix not a data.frame. If your values are not numeric like this example that may cause some issues.

There are some alternate ways to do this using Data Tables or dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df1), V1~paste0("V", rowid(V1)+1))
#   V1 V2 V3
#1: 10  5 10
#2: 20  4  7
#3: 30  8  4
#4: 40  6  9
```